# Array being corrupted

Tags: c

When I run this program I want a list of 0s and 1s, but instead I get a list of 0s, 1s, and a bunch of random numbers positive and negative. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randomInt(maxNum) {
  return (rand() % maxNum - 1) + 1;
}

int main(void) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int board[100];
  int index = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
    board[randomInt(100)] = 1;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    printf("%i\n", board[index]);
    index ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You only set at most 20 entries in the array. All the other entries will have indeterminate values.

Comment: you also get out-of-bound access: `randomInt(100)` returns values from 1 to 100 but `board` contains only indices 0..99

Comment: @phuclv: Actually, thanks to operator precedence, it's still returning values from 0 to 99. It does `rand() % maxNum` *first*, then dutifully subtracts `1`, then adds it back. So the OP's intent was wrong, and with optimizations off it may generate wasteful code, but they didn't do what they intended and it ended up right anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't initialize `board`, so it has indeterminate values in every cell but the 20 (or fewer) you assigned `1` to. Explicitly initialize it with zeroes:

```
 int board[100] = {0};
```

to avoid treating random garbage on the stack as the initial values. I'd also suggest turning up compiler warnings (it *should* recognize the failure to initialize, though the pseudo-random partial initialization might fool it in this case).

Answer (score 0):

per [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)
the `-` operator has higher precedence than the `%` operator, so the subtraction will be performed before the modulo operation. therefore, the call to `randomInt()` returns values in the range 1...99 which is OK.

Running the posted code through a compiler with the warnings enabled:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" -o "untitled2.o"
```

results in:

```
untitled2.c: In function ‘randomInt’:

untitled2.c:5:5: warning: type of ‘maxNum’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
    5 | int randomInt(maxNum) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~

untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled2.c:10:9: warning: conversion from ‘time_t’ {aka ‘long int’} to ‘unsigned int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   10 |   srand(time(NULL));
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

As others have commented, initialize the `board[]` to a known value, like 0

You can correct the signature of `randomInt()` via:

```
int randomInt( int maxNum) {
```

You can eliminate the warning about `conversion to unsigned` via:

```
srand( (unsigned) time(NULL));
```

regarding:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    printf("%i\n", board[index]);
    index ++;
}
```

This can be simplified so it does not introduce another variable via:

```
for ( index = 0; index < 100; index++ ) 
{
    printf( "%i\n", board[index] );
}
```

Comment: You're misreading the operator precedence rules; binary `%` is higher precedence than *binary* `-` (*unary* `-` has higher precedence than either, but it's not what the OP is using). `(rand() % maxNum - 1) + 1;` is for all practical purposes equivalent to `rand() % maxNum`; it'll get a result between 0 and 99 inclusive for `maxNum == 100` (`rand() % (maxNum - 1) + 1;` would get 1 to 99 inclusive). Either way it's in bounds, but 0 to 99 includes the whole array, 1 to 99 would omit the first index.

Comment: @ShadowRanger.   the operators + and - are in group 2,  urinary plus and minus.  group 2 is evaluated from right to left.  group 2 has higher precedence than group 3.  The modulo operator `%` is in group 3. group 3 is evaluated left to right  Therefore,, the `-` is evaluated before the `%`

Comment: Okay, one, you meant "unary", not "urinary" (unfortunate typo there). Two, unary `+` and `-` mean usage like `+a` (largely unused) and `-a` (negation, changing a positive number to the negative equivalent and vice versa); unary means "applies to one operand". Keep reading; group 4 is where addition and subtraction (the binary operands used for stuff like `a + b` and `a - b`) come in. The unary `-` would be evaluated first in an expression like `-a % b`, not in an expression like `a - b % c` (where `b % c` would be evaluated first, then subtracted from `a`).